# python scikit-learn decisonTreeRegressor and RandomForestRegression

Tags: python, arrays

I try built fit with DecisionTreeRegressor and RandomForestRegressor but RandomForestRegressor return this error:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:5: DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples,), for example using ravel().
```

`data_array` is a numpy matrix and `y_array` is a numpy array nx1

this code:

```py
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data_array, y_array, test_size = 0.20,     random_state = 42)

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
clf = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth = 10, 
                         random_state = 0)

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
# Predict for 1 observation
y_pred=clf.predict(X_test)
```

works right

this code:

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
rf_model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=30, random_state=0)
rf_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
# Predict for 1 observation
y_pred=rf_model.predict(X_test)
```

doesn't work

the error message writes:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:5: DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples,), for example using ravel().
```

why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the issue is, `DecisionTreeRegressor` works fine with a column-vector as the target variable. it can handle multi-dimensional arrays. but, `RandomForestRegressor` expects a 1D array as the target variable.

convert `y_train` to a 1D array using the `ravel()` method:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

y_train_1d = y_train.ravel()

rf_model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=30, random_state=0)
rf_model.fit(X_train, y_train_1d)

y_pred = rf_model.predict(X_test)
```